# Append element to a list flutter firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm currently working with FLutter and firebase. I'm trying to upload some data to the cloud firestore. So far so good. I have a problem when I'd like to append to a field a list.
As mentioned before this field contains a list of values defined as below:

```
Map<String, Object> toDocument() {
  Map customerAddress = Map();
  Map orderCheckoutDetails = Map();

  final DateTime now = DateTime.now();
  final DateFormat formatter = DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy');
  final String formatted = formatter.format(now);

  customerAddress['address'] = this.address;
  customerAddress['city'] = this.city;
  customerAddress['state'] = this.state;
  customerAddress['zipCode'] = this.zipCode;

  orderCheckoutDetails['checkoutOrderDate'] = formatted;
  orderCheckoutDetails['customerAddress'] = customerAddress;
  orderCheckoutDetails['customerName'] = '${this.nome!} ${this.cognome!}';
  orderCheckoutDetails['customerPhone'] = this.numeroTelefono!;
  orderCheckoutDetails['products'] = this.products!.map((product) => product.name).toList();
  orderCheckoutDetails['subtotal'] = this.subtotal!;
  orderCheckoutDetails['deliveryFee'] = this.deliveryFee!;
  orderCheckoutDetails['total'] = this.total!;
  List<Map<dynamic, dynamic>> orderList = [orderCheckoutDetails];

  return {
    'orderCheckoutDetails': orderList,
  };
}
```

This is how it shows me the item on Firebase (which is correct).
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bbla6.png)

This is how I upload the document to Firebase.

```
 @override
 Future<void> addCheckout(Checkout checkout) async {
  print(checkout.email!);

  final docExists = await _checkIfUserCheckoutExists(checkout.email!);
  print(docExists);

  if (!docExists) {
  return _checkoutCollection
      .doc(checkout.email!)
      .set(checkout.toDocument());
  } else {
    await _checkoutCollection.doc(checkout.email!).update({
    "orderCheckoutDetails":
        FieldValue.arrayUnion(checkout.toDocument() as List)
  });
}
```

}

**What I'd like to do is to append at the end of the document another element (the checkout element passed by parameter). How can I do that?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your can use `set` with merge option in both cases (whether the document exists or not), it will create or update the document as needed. Plus your `toDocument` method should return `orderList` itself, not the map you are currently returning.

Try this:

```
Map<dynamic, dynamic> toDocument() {
  Map customerAddress = Map();
  Map<dynamic, dynamic> orderCheckoutDetails = Map();

  final DateTime now = DateTime.now();
  final DateFormat formatter = DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy');
  final String formatted = formatter.format(now);

  customerAddress['address'] = this.address;
  customerAddress['city'] = this.city;
  customerAddress['state'] = this.state;
  customerAddress['zipCode'] = this.zipCode;

  orderCheckoutDetails['checkoutOrderDate'] = formatted;
  orderCheckoutDetails['customerAddress'] = customerAddress;
  orderCheckoutDetails['customerName'] = '${this.nome!} ${this.cognome!}';
  orderCheckoutDetails['customerPhone'] = this.numeroTelefono!;
  orderCheckoutDetails['products'] = this.products!.map((product) => product.name).toList();
  orderCheckoutDetails['subtotal'] = this.subtotal!;
  orderCheckoutDetails['deliveryFee'] = this.deliveryFee!;
  orderCheckoutDetails['total'] = this.total!;

  return orderCheckoutDetails;
}
```

And then create / insert your document like:

```
return _checkoutCollection
  .doc(checkout.email!)
  .set({
    'orderCheckoutDetails' : FieldValue.arrayUnion([checkout.toDocument])
   }, SetOptions(merge: true));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using FieldValue.arrayUnion([data]) this way in firebase doc

```
addToScoreLog({required int newLoggedScore, required String userIdF}) {
final data = {
  "loggedScore": 20,
  "createdAt": DateTime.now(), // this will be saved in TimeStamp Formate
};
//
_scoreDataBaseRef.doc('docID').update({
  "scoresLog": FieldValue.arrayUnion([data])
}).whenComplete(() => log('ScoreDataBase Call: added To Logged Score'));
}
```

[image]

[image]

read more Here [enter link description here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array)